# nanmean of matrix columns in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to take the `nanmean` of columns in matrix in Python.

For example:

```
import numpy as np  
a = [[np.nan,2,3,4],[5,np.nan,7,8],[9,10,np.nan,12]] 
a =
matrix([[ nan,   2.,   3.,   4.],
        [  5.,  nan,   7.,   8.],
        [  9.,  10.,  nan,  12.]])
```

The current command returns 6.66.

I would like something like `np.nanmean(a)` that will return `[7,6,5,8]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the keyword `axis=0` to achieve the result!

```
import numpy as np  
a=[[np.nan,2,3,4],[5,np.nan,7,8],[9,10,np.nan,12]] 

>>> np.nanmean(a, axis=0)
array([ 7.,  6.,  5.,  8.])
```

See the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) for details.

Omitting the keyword will give the mean of all entries of the matrix that are not `np.nan`.